# Getting 256-bit AES SSL on Heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, aes

I'm trying to port my existing Heroku app to use SSL throughout.  The customer wants *only* 256-bit AES SSL.  I  don't see any documentation on Heroku about what ciphers they offer, or even where to configure this setting.

Is it possible to change the settings?  Does Heroku handle all that automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku SSL comes in one flavour only.  You'll need to [ask support](https://support.heroku.com/home) for the specifics.

However, there's nothing to stop you from creating your own SSL endpoint that proxies traffic to Heroku if your client has a very specific set of requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Heroku supports the following cipher suites:

You can find that out as by using the SSL Test of ssllab.com:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=heroku.com&s=23.21.198.2

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f) 128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 128, Ys: 128)   FS   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x41)    128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x45)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 128, Ys: 128)   FS  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)   ECDH 233 bits (eq. 2048 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH 233 bits (eq. 2048 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa) 168
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x16)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 128, Ys: 128)   FS  168
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)   ECDH 233 bits (eq. 2048 bits RSA)   FS   168
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35) 256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 128, Ys: 128)   FS   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x84)    256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x88)   DH 1024 bits (p: 128, g: 128, Ys: 128)   FS  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH 233 bits (eq. 2048 bits RSA)   FS
```